# Fix the background-image so it fits the rounded corners

Tags: html, background, rounded-corners, css

Are there any way to fix the background image so it doesn't go outside the borders that are rounded?
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PCzFC/102/)

Pure CSS solution is preferable.

The code is here:

```
<style>
div {
border-radius: 30px;
background-color: #dddddd;
margin:60px;
}

a{
position: relative;
display: block;
height: 90px;
padding: 15px;
background-image: url("http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/stsc2r2vqd1y6ps/lab.png");
background-position: 0 top;
background-repeat: repeat;
}
</style>
<div><a href="#">some text</a></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because you're not preventing the inner content from overflowing the boundaries of the divider. To fix this, simply add `overflow: hidden` to your `div`:

```css
div {
    ...
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the background image to your *div* container, I've modified your jsfiddle:

```
div {
border-radius: 30px;
background-color: #dddddd;
background-image: url("http://www.moveoneinc.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Dog-2.jpg");
background-position: 0 top;
background-repeat: repeat;
margin:60px;
}

a{
position: relative;
display: block;
height: 90px;
padding: 15px;
}
```

The other image you had didn't work, so I changed it..
EDIT: Someone got me by 1 sec, I think that the overflow solution is also valid :)